# How to count the occurrence of strings in Dataframe that exists in another list of dicts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which look like this:

```
                   ngram
--------------------------
  0                    []
  1   [_ting, tingk, ...]
  2   [_pend, pendi, ...]
  3   [_teat, teate, ...]
...                   ...
999                    []
```

I also have a list of dicts which look like this:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Academic",
    "gram": "_ting"
  },
  {
    "label": "Facility",
    "gram": "_pend"
  },
  ....,
  {
    "label": "Others",
    "gram": "meing"
  },
]
```

How to count the occurrence of the words in the Dataframe, by checking whether if it exists in the list or not? My desire output is like this which will be used for the next computation:

```
academic_count = 1
facility_count = 1
services_count = 0
others_count   = 0
```

I managed to implement it, but I'm just using nested looping, 
which extremely slow because of the length of the Dataframe (1000 data) and the length of the list (4000+ data). This is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ngram'] = data

academic_chance = []
facility_chance = []
services_chance = []
others_chance   = []

for idx, ngram_words in enumerate(df['ngram']):
    academic_probs = []
    facility_probs = []
    services_probs = []
    others_probs   = []

    for ngram in ngram_words:
        academic_count = 0
        facility_count = 0
        services_count = 0
        others_count   = 0

        for item in list_of_dicts:
            if ngram == item["gram"] and item["label"] == "Academic":
                academic_count += 1
            elif ngram == item["gram"] and item["label"] == "Facility":
                facility_count += 1
            elif ngram == item["gram"] and item["label"] == "Services":
                services_count += 1
            elif ngram == item["gram"] and item["label"] == "Others":
                others_count += 1

        academic_cond_prob = (academic_count + 1) / academic_denominator
        facility_cond_prob = (facility_count + 1) / facility_denominator
        services_cond_prob = (services_count + 1) / services_denominator
        others_cond_prob   = (others_count   + 1) / others_denominator

        academic_probs.append(academic_cond_prob)
        facility_probs.append(facility_cond_prob)
        services_probs.append(services_cond_prob)
        others_probs.append(others_cond_prob)

    academic_chance.append(np.prod(academic_probs) * academic_cat_probs)
    facility_chance.append(np.prod(facility_probs) * facility_cat_probs)
    services_chance.append(np.prod(services_probs) * services_cat_probs)
    others_chance.append(np.prod(others_probs)     * others_cat_probs)
```

Any ideas on how to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is first change list of dicts to dictinary in dict comprehension:

```
L = [
  {
    "label": "Academic",
    "gram": "_ting"
  },
  {
    "label": "Facility",
    "gram": "_pend"
  },
  {
    "label": "Services",
    "gram": "_aaa"
  },
  {
    "label": "Others",
    "gram": "meing"
  },
]

d = {x['gram']:x['label'] for x in L}
print (d)
{'_ting': 'Academic', '_pend': 'Facility', '_aaa': 'Services', 'meing': 'Others'}
```

Then is used [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) for indicators in new `DataFrame`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['ngram']),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df1)
   _pend  _teat  _ting  pendi  teate  tingk
0      0      0      0      0      0      0
1      0      0      1      0      0      1
2      1      0      0      1      0      0
3      0      1      0      0      1      0
```

Last filter only columns by values of keys in dictionary, coun them by `sum`, `rename` by dictionary for groups and last add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for add non matched groups:

```
s = (df1.loc[:, df1.columns.isin(list(d.keys()))]
        .sum()
        .rename(d)
        .sum(level=0)
        .reindex(list(d.values()), fill_value=0))
print (s)
Academic    1
Facility    1
Services    0
Others      0
dtype: int64
```

If need for each values separate variable:

```
academic_count = s['Academic']
facility_count = s['Facility']
services_count = s['Services']
others_count   = s['Others']
```